# How to display all fields?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I'm using `hibernate 4.2.6` and `Spring 4.0.1`
Let we have entity class `Sale` which contains the following fields:

```
private int id;
private String name;
private int count;
private int sum;
private Date date;
```

I have database which contains several row, corresponding to this entity. I want to display any of this fields in the `jsp` page:

```
<c:forEach var="sale" begin="0" step="1" items="${sales}">
    ${sale.name}
    ${sale.count}
    ${sale.sum}
    ${sale.date}
</c:forEach>
```

`sales` is `List<Sale>` of `sale` here.

But I don't want to type this fields manually. Is there a way to do it automatically?

Comment: what is sales here object or list or something else?

Comment: @M.Sharma sales is List<Sale>

Comment: Define `don't want to type this fields manually`?

Comment: @M.Sharma That is, display fileds for instnce with reflection.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
    <c:forEach var="sale" items="${sales}">
        <c:forEach var="field" items="${sale.class.declaredFields}">
            <!--To catch NoSuchFieldException,SecurityException-->
            <c:catch>Field Name:${field.name} - Field Value:${sale[field.name]}  
            </c:catch>          
        </c:forEach>
    </c:forEach>
```

Java equivalent of this is:

```
if(sale.getClass().getDeclaredFields() != null){
    for(Field field : sale.getClass().getDeclaredFields()){
        System.out.println("Field Name:"+field.getName());
        System.out.println("Field value:"+field.get(sale));
    }
}
```

This will display fine as long as Sale has simple data types as fields. If it has say a List myList, it will display as: myList[str1, str2].